# Hacer un menú con varios sub menú de opciones

Tags: java, netbeans

¿Como podría ejecutar esta historia clínica -o sea, un menú con diferentes sub menú desde netbeans? Lo intenté pero me quede en esto:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package historiaclinica;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Tadeo
 */
public class HistoriaClinica {
    private String Paciente;
    private String Medico;
    private String HistorialClinico;


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //menu historia clinica
        int opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Historial Clinico\n\n 1.Gestionar Pacientes\n 2.Gestionar Medicos\n 3.Gestionar Historial Clinico\n 4.Salir"));

        switch (opcion){
            case 1:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gestionar Pacientes");
                break;
            case 2:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gestionar Medicos");
                break;
            case 3:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gestionar Historial Clinico");
                break;
            case 4:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Salir");
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta");
                break;

        }
int paciente=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gestionar Pacientes\n\n 1.Registrar Pacientes\n 2.Mostrar Pacientes\n 3.Modificar Pacientes\n 4.Eliminar Pacientes\n 5.Atras"));
switch (paciente){
            case 1:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Registrar Pacientes");
                break;
            case 2:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Mostrar Pacientes");
                break;
            case 3:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Modificar Pacientes");
                break;
            case 4:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Eliminar Pacientes");
                break;
            case 5:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Atras");
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta");
    }
    int medico=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gestionar Medicos\n\n 1.Registrar Medico\n 2.Mostrar Medico\n 3.Modificar Medico\n 4.Eliminar Medico\n 5.Atras"));
        switch (medico){
            case 1:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Registrar Medico");
                break;
            case 2:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Mostrar Medico");
                break;
            case 3:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Modificar Medico");
                break;
            case 4:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Eliminar Medico");
                break;
            case 5:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Atras");
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta");
    }
        int historialclinico=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gestionar Historial Clinico\n\n 1.Registrar Historial Clinico\n 2.Mostrar Historial Clinico\n 3.Modificar Historial Clinico\n 4.Eliminar Historial Clinico\n 5.Atras"));
        switch (historialclinico){
            case 1:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Registrar Historial Clinico");
                break;
            case 2:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Mostrar Historial Clinico");
                break;
            case 3:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Modificar Historial Clinico");
                break;
            case 4:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Eliminar Historial Clinico");
                break;
            case 5:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Atras");
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta");
    }

 }       
  }
```

Comment: Una barra de menú en una ventana no te sería útil?

Comment: Hola Tadeo Marinero, te doy la bienvenida! Te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso obtener tu primera medalla :) También es importante que revises **[Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo hacer un menú principal. Y en cada opción de tu menú principal, hacer una llamada mediante un método a tus subMenus. Te haré un ejemplo con Paciente.

Nuestro método dameMenuPaciente, que nos devuelve el submenu de paciente.

```
public static void dameMenuPaciente() {
    int paciente = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gestionar Pacientes\n\n 1.Registrar Pacientes\n 2.Mostrar Pacientes\n 3.Modificar Pacientes\n 4.Eliminar Pacientes\n 5.Atras"));
    switch (paciente) {
        case 1:
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Registrar Pacientes");
            break;
        case 2:
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Mostrar Pacientes");
            break;
        case 3:
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Modificar Pacientes");
            break;
        case 4:
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Eliminar Pacientes");
            break;
        case 5:
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Atras");
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta");
    }
}
```

Nuestro main quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Historial Clinico\n\n 1.Gestionar Pacientes\n 2.Gestionar Medicos\n 3.Gestionar Historial Clinico\n 4.Salir"));

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                dameMenuPaciente();
                break;
            case 2:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gestionar Medicos");
                break;
            case 3:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gestionar Historial Clinico");
                break;
            case 4:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Salir");
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Opcion Incorrecta");
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta

Comment: kimbo  muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ahora tengo que hacer esto con cada una de las categorías? y después cada categoría tiene sus opciónes después.. por ejemplo en el menú gestionar pacientes tengo 4- opciones 1- registrar 2-mostrar 3-modificar 4-eliminar 5-atras. asi cada menú

Comment: Te recomendaría eso, si. Meter tus subsmenus en métodos, y a la hora de llamarlos simplementes metes dichos métodos. Es mucho más fácil y tendrás tu código organizado.

Comment: Hola kimbo necesito tu ayuda nuevamente.. necesito hacer en este mismo proyecto lo q sigue ósea registrar cada ítem por ejemplo en pacientes.. modificar, mostrar, eliminar y atrás.. necesito cada una de esas funciones por favor si me podrías realizar una a modo de ejemplo

Comment: Buenas Tadeo. Esto realmente no tiene mucha complicación. Al igual que te he mostrado con el submenú de pacientes, hazlo con todos tus submenus.